# List the files within a .gz archive using C# / SharpLib

Tags: c#, gzip, sharpziplib

Is there a way to list the filenames insize a .gz file without decompressing it. I'm using SharpLib and for Zip it provides GetNextEntry in zipInputStream to get ZipEntry with which we get the filenames and other attributes. But this is not directly available in GZip of SharpLib library..

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can simply decode the gzip header yourself to get the file name (there is only one).  Look at [RFC 1952](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1952.txt) for the header description.

The gzip utility will not use that name unless asked to.  When decompressing, gzip will use the name of the compressed file, and just drop the ".gz".  If you use `-N`, it will use the name in the gzip header instead.